# Backbone templates: Using HBS to dynamically switch templates

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I found [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997828/backbone-managing-templates) on here of how to use the HBS plug-in to manage templates.  It seems like a great solution.  @machineghost suggests using RequireJS to include templates like this:

```
define(['template!path/to/someTemplate'], function(someTemplate) {
    var MyNewView = BaseView.extend({template: someTemplate});
    $('body').append(new MyNewView().render().el);
}
```

This is great, except I need to dynamically switch templates.  Here is an example of one of my views:

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'models/tableModel',
    'collections/tablesCollection',
    'views/tablesView'
], function($, _, Backbone, tableModel, tablesCollection, tablesView) {
    var t = new tablesCollection(null, {url: 'applications-lab'});
    return new tablesView({ collection: t, template: 'applications-lab-template', url: 'applications-lab'});
});
```

As you can seem, I'm passing in the template when the view is rendered.  What I'm wondering is can I pass in a variable to the `define` statement that would tell Backbone which template path to use?  I'm a newbie to Backbone and especially RequireJS, and am not sure.  Suggestions anyone?

Comment: I mean the first define statement above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Preliminary notes:

- require.js does not allow parameters in a module definition, define accepts a dependency array and a definition function :

  ```
  define(['dep1', 'dep2', ...], function(dep1, dep2) {
  })
  ```
- I would not define a view, instantiate it and inject its el in the same module but feel free to mix and match to your taste

Let's start with a module defining a simple view with a default template, let's say *views/templated.js*

```
define(['backbone', 'hbs!path/to/defaultTemplate'], 
    function(Backbone, defaultTemplate) {

    var MyNewView = Backbone.View.extend({
        template: defaultTemplate,

        initialize: function(opts) {
            opts = opts || {};

            // use the template defined in the options or on the prototype
            this.template = opts.template || this.template; 
        }
     });

     return MyNewView;
});
```

Now you just have to pull you view definition and an optional template with require:

```
require(['views/templated', 'hbs!path/to/anotherTemplate'], 
    function(MyNewView, anotherTemplate) {

    // a view with the default template
    var v1 = new MyNewView();

    // a view with a new template
    var v2 = new MyNewView({
        template: anotherTemplate
    });
});
```

To create a new class with an overridden default template, you would define a new module (*views/override.js*)

```
define(['views/templated', 'hbs!path/to/anotherTemplate'], 
    function(MyNewView, anotherTemplate) {

    var AnotherNewView = MyNewView.extend({
        template: anotherTemplate
     });

     return AnotherNewView;
});
```

Finally, you can always change the template on a given instance by directly assigning a new value.

```
var v = new MyNewView();
v.template = tpl;
```

A Fiddle simulating the views hierarchy : http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/URddR/

Coming back to your code, your blocks could look like

```
require(['models/tableModel', 'collections/tablesCollection', 'views/templated', 'applications-lab-template'], 
    function(tableModel, tablesCollection, tablesView, tpl) {

    var t = new tablesCollection(null, {url: 'applications-lab'});
    var v = new tablesView({
        collection: t,
        template: tpl
        url: 'applications-lab'
    });

    // or, if you prefer and you don't render in initialize
    v.template = tpl;
});
```